# Why do I get this unexpected syntax error on the Python console?

Tags: python

[image]i'm trying to get output from a list, but i get a weird syntax error.

```
facecountt = []
for polygon in bpy.context.scene.objects['Torus'].data.polygons:    
    facecountt.append(polygon.index)
print(facecountt[2])
```

i don't get why it won't work.
whatever i try - for as long as the list is filled with polygon.index i get this error, even when i tried to convert the values to integers.
i can print polygon.index itself, but not within the list.

Comment: Please show the [weird syntax error] which is really your friend. Screen capture or cut and paste.

Comment: Try running it from a file. It's working fine for me...

Comment: I am executing the Python below from a text window.  It has a button [Run Script].  I have a mesh of the expected name in my window.  Note I printed the whole list ...not the element 2 .... [2].

Comment: it seems to work, when i run it from a file.
problem solved, still a mystery, why the console can't handle it

Comment: use `bpy.data.objects['torus'].data.polygons` , not context.scene...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This behavior is intended and is how Python knows you intend to terminate a loop. You have to end the `for` block, by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> on an empty line, before writing anything outside it.

Oppose:

```
>>> f = []
>>> for p in bpy.context.scene.objects['Torus'].data.polygons:
...     f.append(p.index)
... print(f) #Notice how this line starts with an ellipsis
```

With:

```
>>> f = []
>>> for p in bpy.context.scene.objects['Torus'].data.polygons:
...     f.append(p.index) #Hit enter _twice_ after this line
...
>>> print(f) #Notice how this line starts with three greater than symbols
```

---

Note that this isn't specific to Blender, the same behavior can be [found in Python's default console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391633/blank-line-rule-at-interactive-prompt) - just by running "python" from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

**Execution from the Text Editor Window**

import bpy ...... If you have a list to print you may find it useful to interate through the list.

```
import bpy
facecountt = []
for polygon in bpy.context.scene.objects['Torus'].data.polygons:    
    facecountt.append(polygon.index)

print(facecountt)
for p in facecountt:
    print(p)
```